# EF Core, reusable IQueryable<T> filter for multiple properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a `Product` model with several properties, I'm trying to build a text based search that can filter by specified properties which are either int or date. Each support a syntax such as `followers:50..100`, `buyers:>=50`, `watchers:<10`, this works fine for a single property where queryable is `IQueryable<Product>` from EF Core context, basic example:

```
if (filterType == FilterType.Followers) 
{
  var m = Regex.Match(word, @"^(\d+)..(\d+)$");
  if (m.Success)
  {
    queryable = queryable.Where(p => p.FollowerCount >= int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value) && p.FollowerCount <= int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value));
  }
  else
  {
    var digitChars = new string(word.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
    if (int.TryParse(digitChars, out int intValue))
    {
      if (word.StartsWith(">=")) queryable = queryable.Where(p => p.FollowerCount >= intValue);
      else if (word.StartsWith(">")) queryable = queryable.Where(p => p.FollowerCount > intValue);
      else if (word.StartsWith("<=")) queryable = queryable.Where(p => p.FollowerCount <= intValue);
      else if (word.StartsWith("<")) queryable = queryable.Where(p => p.FollowerCount < intValue);
      else queryable = queryable.Where(p => p.FollowerCount == intValue);
    }
  }
}
```

But now I want to reuse this for different int properties, i.e:

```
if (filterType == FilterType.Followers) 
{
  queryable = applyIntFilterQueryable(queryable, p => p.FollowerCount, word);
}
else if (filterType == FilterType.Watchers)
{
  queryable = applyIntFilterQueryable(queryable, p => p.WatcherCount, word);
}
else if (filterType == FilterType.Buyers)
{
  queryable = applyIntFilterQueryable(queryable, p => p.BuyerCount, word); 
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this without manually building the entire expression tree while still keeping it executing on the server side, not client side?

I've tried DynamicLINQ which does seem to make it possible, but ideally I'd like to avoid taking on a dependency and DynamicLINQ seems like overkill.

Note: this is a basic example, the date filtering syntax is more complex so building a full expression tree quickly gets unwieldy and seems like there could be an easier way I'm perhaps missing?

Comment: [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-7.0)

Comment: Doh, thanks @AlexanderPetrov I knew I was overthinking it. Read about `EF.Property` a few months ago too but must have completely forgot, thanks again!